# How to compare two table matching and non matching in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to display matching and non matching records. I have two tables(one having server data and one having clients input data).I need to compare both the values.
pls help how I can do it.

**SERVER TABLE DATA **

| DATA1 | DATA2 | DATA3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HELLO1 | HI-1 | CARE-1 |
| HELLO2 | HI-2 | CARE-2 |

**Client's Input  TABLE DATA **

| DATA1 | DATA2 | DATA3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HELLO1 | HI-1 | CARE |
| HELLO | HI-2 | CARE-2 |

output required:-

```
DATA1 : Matched
DATA2 : Matched
DATA3 : Not-Matched
```

Comment: Perhaps `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`? It is unclear what the logic is here, if i am honest.

Comment: What do "matching" and "non matching" mean to you? I see why `DATA2` match, in that both datasets have the same count of rows and values in that column. And I see why `DATA3` does not match. But why do you think `DATA1` _does_ match? The value in the 2nd row of that column differs between the datasets. What is the logic? [Edit] to explain that clearly. Otherwise, readers are largely guessing, wasting both sides' time.

Comment: this is just an example..i have a long actual data which i cant post here

Comment: "just an example" is fine, *unless* it doesn't clearly indicate what results you want... which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm . . . If the columns have the same type, then perhaps unpivoting and a full-join for matching.  The final step is aggregation:

```
select col,
       (case when count(val) = count(*) then 'Matched'
             else 'Non-matched'
        end)
from (t1 cross join lateral
      (values (t1.data1, 'data1', 1), 
              (t1.data2, 'data2', 1),
              (t1.data3, 'data3', 1)
      ) v(col, val, which)
     ) full join
     (t2 cross join lateral
      (values (t2.data1, 'data1', 2), 
              (t2.data2, 'data2', 2),
              (t2.data3, 'data3', 2)
      ) v(col, val, which)
     )
     using (col, val)
group by col;
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP :)